# Error with the header styling in StackNavigator from React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `StackNavigator` from `React Navigation`, I want to add header styling for Android Platform, but after I have added extra styling I got an error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {style}).If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array
>   instead.

Here is my code:

```
   static navigationOptions ={
      header: {
     style: {
       marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 24 : 0
     }
   }
   }
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: are you using custom header?

Comment: Why do you want to add marginTop? ReactNavigation is taking care of that.

Comment: It looks good in IOS, but in Android there is an overlapping between Android status bar in the top and StackNavigaror bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you are using is deprecated.

You can use following code,

```
static navigationOptions = {
   headerStyle: { marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 24 : 0 }
}
```